# Restarting a bricked Android phone

Tags: 8.0-oreo, 7.1-nougat, lenovo

My Lenovo K8 Note has bricked. I am able to format it with ‘Smart Phone Flash tool’ (Mediatek). I wanted to know how I can load Android on it and restart it. I tried to format it and it was successful. When I tried various versions of Android (Nougat and Oreo) the phone did not start. While I had loaded Nougat nothing happened after I downloaded it on phone, on downloading Oreo, the welcome screen went into a loop. Presently the phone is in formatted condition.

I wanted to know the following:

- If I format the phone and simply download the latest version of Android in it, will the phone start working? (something like assembled PCs where I can format the HDD and load a version of Windows for it to start). If so, which version of Android should I use? Pls. point me to the downloadable ROM file. (the phone originally came with Nougat)
- If the above technique is not possible, what should I do to revive my smart phone? Before the phone bricked on its own, I had not unlocked the bootloader (never had any requirement to do so).

I don’t want to buy a new phone in the present economic condition. Hence, pls. guide me on how to revive the device. Any pointers will be gratefully acknowledged.

Comment: if you format your device it becomes a brick https://blog.hovatek.com/so-whats-all-this-talk-about-meditek-secure-boot-and-da-files

Comment: OK. Yes I had to format my device as it was not responding to a Nougat or Oreo downloads. What can i do to revive my phone pls?

Comment: flash a stock ROM and try to recover IMEI and calibration data from scratch

Comment: Download your phone's original software from the device maker and reinstall to its released state.

Comment: Where do i get stock ROM for Lenovo K8 note pls? The website is too big to search. Initially the device was launched for Android 7.1. I tried to use Lenovo's recovery tool. The phone is going in a welcome screen loop.Thanks.

Comment: you need to recover nvram partition

Comment: if you weren't lazy you would have already read that other question suggested and found this [link](https://repairmymobile.in/flash/lenovo-xt1902-3-flash-file)

Comment: I tried the solution in the link. The phone is going into a welcome screen loop. In fact previously I had tried a similar solution at XDA website. Then also eh welcome screen was going into a loop.